# How can I add items to a dropdownlist from a struct asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm struggling on how I can add multiple items to a dropdownlist comming from data:

```
#region OBTER UMA LISTA DE IDS DE ENCOMENDA DA PESSOA 
conex.Open();
List<EncomendaID> encomendas = new List<EncomendaID>();

SqlCommand SelectEncomendas = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID_Encomenda FROM Encomenda WHERE PessoaID='" + pessoaID + "'", conex);

SqlDataReader leitor = SelectEncomendas.ExecuteReader();

EncomendaID encomenda = new EncomendaID();

while (leitor.Read())
{
    encomenda = new EncomendaID();
    encomenda.encomendaid = leitor.GetInt32(0);

    encomendas.Add(encomenda);
}

conex.Close();

//ADICIONAR A DROPDOWNLIST AS ENCOMENDAS
dddlEncomendaID.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(encomendas));

#endregion OBTER UMA LISTA DE IDS DE ENCOMENDA DA PESSOA
```

As you can see I'm trying to get certain data from database insert them in a struct then try to add to a dropdownlist but I get a strange error

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrD8X.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are trying to push a list of "EncomendaID" converted to a string into the dropdownlist? You need to loop and put each item separately. You are trying to push the ToString() of the generic list class which is not overriden.

Comment: whether web form or mvc